# Android gradle project directory variable

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to write a script in gradle that requires opening up a file. I am trying to find the current directory where the project is installed. so I can open a file in my "raw" directory.

Note: I am aware that I can use a temporary file to find the current location of the application. However, I am trying to stay away from that solution.

I am trying to find out if gradle has a buildDir variable that I can use in my task instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html).  Specifically, you're interested in `projectDir` (The directory containing the build script) or `buildDir` (projectDir/build).

Comment: Thank you, 'projectDir' is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also use rootProject.file('file_name') to locate the directory of a file in your root project. For anyone looking for other usages.